# Fatal error helper class Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I'me new to Magento. I've created a helper class

/app/etc/modules/Mytrends_MyFunctions.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mytrends_MyFunctions>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mytrends_MyFunctions>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Mytrends/MyFunctions/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
        <Mytrends_MyFunctions>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mytrends_MyFunctions>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <myfunctions>
                <class>Mytrends_MyFunctions_Helper</class>
            </myfunctions>
        </helpers>
     </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Mytrends/MyFunctions/Helper/Data.php :

```
<?php
class Mytrends_MyFunctions_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
        public function test () {
            echo 'hello';
        }
}
?>
```

And i tried to call this test() like this

```
Mage::helper('myfunctions')->test();
```

but i got a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mytrends_MyFunctions_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 548
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the configuration cache?

Comment: a bad habit you should really loose is to close php on a class. You should never ever do this. please read stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/

Answer (score 0):

you have to call helper function like this:

```
Mage::helper('mytrends/myfunctions')->test();
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your module config.xml file path properly.

Comment: I'm sorry, It was my mistake, I wrote wrong file name here.

Answer (score 0):

This file doesn't have to right name : `/app/etc/modules/config.xml` it should be `/app/etc/modules/Mytrends_MyFunctions.xml`

Comment: I'm sorry, It was my mistake, I wrote wrong file name here.

Comment: Except from that I don't see any mistake at first glance. Are you sure you didn't misplaced a file ? Looking at your error, it looks like an error coming from the file `/app/code/local/Mytrends/MyFunctions/Helper/Data.php` being misplaced or the class name of this helper being mistyped.